# How can I prevent holy aura from a human body from radiating too strongly?

Tags: biology, environment, gods, radiation

When gods descend to the mortal plane, they must inhabit specially built bodies in order to maintain their presence and hold their aethereal energies. These bodies are built in the aethereal realm with Godtech and made in the image of a human being. Since the essence of a God is so large, the smallest these bodies can be made is in the 8 - 9 ft range. Within the physical form is a large core that contains the god's essence. This core functions similar to a miniature nuclear reactor that powers the body and allows the god to control it like a puppet.

Even with these specialized forms, the gods essence is so strong can't be perfectly contained, radiating from the body in a golden hue. This divine radiation bathes the surrounding area with divine energy, including the sentient beings within that area. Human beings can experience various affects from this aura, including light headedness, extreme pressure, shortness of breath, and unconsciousness. Even heart attacks can occur in certain people, which can be fatal.

These gods need to keep their divine aura at benign levels to prevent it from radiating too strongly from their physical forms, so that it doesn't completely overwhelm the humans surrounding it. Mortals must feel the majesty of their presence without suffering the ill affects. I would also like to keep the God's form as biological as possible, to keep the appeared center of a highly advanced being.

What is the best way to make this happen?

Comment: Pretty vague, but I upvoted it just because I like the concept of a godlike being trying not to irradiate his subjects with his own divine light. That said, the limiting factor seems to be the golden color. That's a specific frequency that doesn't easily travel through blood and muscle and such. So either this light is so intense that it goes through that stuff anyway (which is hard to imagine without this body being basically on fire) or the radiance is produced very close to the skin. Maybe the reactor requires a glowing coolant that flows through the avatar's veins?

Comment: This is precisely why I shower regularly and wear clean clothing...to keep my aura from overwhelming everybody else on the bus.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What the god needs is a heat-sink.  An object which they can focus their excess awesomeness into so that it doesn't pour out into their surroundings.  This is why many gods are associated with the objects which they carry. (Thor's hammer, Poseidon's trident, etc.)  Those aren't really weapons because god's don't need weapons to be safe from mere humans.  The objects are power-sinks, slowly being transformed by the god's will at the atomic level.

At the beginning of a god's incarnation, the object might be made of some lightweight material like wood.  During the incarnation's stay on the human plain, it slowly transforms into denser and denser metals.  If the god stays too long, the object reaches the unstable radioactive densities, causing a brand new type of aura problem.

The incredible density of objects left behind after divine visits might also explain how some myths came into being.  ...only the worthy can pull the sword from the stone or lift the hammer.

Answer (score 4):

## Gold-dust Shellac.

A rare and dense metal that has been used by rulers to enhance their health, strength and fitness to rule for [thousands of years](https://magic-spells-and-potions.com/magical_properties_of_metal.htm#Gold):

> Gold is the sun metal. It has therefore been linked over the millennia
> with everything to do with health, wealth, and growth.

- reflects not just the golden radiance of the God back into itself, but itself is a symbol of both supreme [Good and Evil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold#Culture).

> Moses was instructed to cover the Mercy Seat of the Ark of the
> Covenant with pure gold.

And what more fitting to give to a God a gift that makes the God not only safe to be around, but still gives them that shine of divinity.

Answer (score 4):

They deplete the energy to lower the power of aura.
Do a little thing on the atoms of the water, create some carbon, mix it well and create a wine. Then they can spend whole night among the people. And maybe the duck that was in that kitchen was turned to well done even without plucking but who cares?
Before going into the city it's good idea to use the energy on... maybe killing some leprosy bacteria? Or when you really need to drain that tank again do some atom welding and create whole leg with muscles and veins. 
Or if you are not into those type of "good deeds" just propel yourself 30 feet into air and disperse the energy creating "sun halo" or "sun arrows".
Maybe post on "medammitgram" "felt energized, might burn a city and rain some frogs later idk".
Or if you are form those "good guys" part of the pantheon spend whole year on selling your energy to some Fair Trade toy makers and then do a Tour De world once a years and give those toys away. That sparkling dust you leave when you dash through the sky always make little kids say "Santa was here!"

Answer (score 0):

Scheme #1: The "Faraday Cage"

Build something similar in concept to a Faraday cage into their clothes - something that diverts the radiation and channels it into a "ground" line. This could be meticulously masked as thick threads or bands woven around their clothes, giving the appearance of wearing gold or platinum weave.

The weaves are connected to an energy-absorbing mechanism disguised as a traveler's bag or backpack. A valve or controller mechanism allows it to selectively leak out a metered amount of energy to let everyone know how awesome they are.

Scheme #2: The Power Armor

Wear a high-tech torso-plate that absorbs the radiation as a power source - this should block it from most angles while protecting from damage and otherwise being extremely functional.